# colorbox jquery pop-up shows text even after closing the window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, colorbox

I am using colorbox jquery for auto pop-up. It works fine but It shows the text (pop up text) even after closing the window. Please let me know the solution. The code as below.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
            <title>Title goes here</title>
            <script src="Scripts/AC_RunActiveContent.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="colorbox/colorbox.css" />
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
            <script>$(document).ready(function(){$.colorbox({inline:true, href:".ajax"});});</script>   

            <script>
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    //Examples of how to assign the Colorbox event to elements
                    $(".group1").colorbox({rel:'group1'});
                    $(".group2").colorbox({rel:'group2', transition:"fade"});
                    $(".group3").colorbox({rel:'group3', transition:"none", width:"75%", height:"75%"});
                    $(".group4").colorbox({rel:'group4', slideshow:true});
                    $(".ajax").colorbox();
                    $(".youtube").colorbox({iframe:true, innerWidth:640, innerHeight:390});
                    $(".vimeo").colorbox({iframe:true, innerWidth:500, innerHeight:409});
                    $(".iframe").colorbox({iframe:true, width:"80%", height:"80%"});
                    $(".inline").colorbox({inline:true, width:"50%"});
                    $(".callbacks").colorbox({
                        onOpen:function(){ alert('onOpen: colorbox is about to open'); },
                        onLoad:function(){ alert('onLoad: colorbox has started to load the targeted content'); },
                        onComplete:function(){ alert('onComplete: colorbox has displayed the loaded content'); },
                        onCleanup:function(){ alert('onCleanup: colorbox has begun the close process'); },
                        onClosed:function(){ alert('onClosed: colorbox has completely closed'); }
                    });

                    $('.non-retina').colorbox({rel:'group5', transition:'none'})
                    $('.retina').colorbox({rel:'group5', transition:'none', retinaImage:true, retinaUrl:true});


                });
            </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class='ajax'>Pop-up text goes here</div>   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is an error in the code above. You have an extra parentheses, right below `//Example of preserving a JavaScript event for inline calls.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added an onCleanup function to your colorbox that will set the display value of any div with the `ajax` class to none so that it is hidden after you close the colorbox.

Ignore the code for colorbox, I needed to include it in the actual answer to have it run in the snippet.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.colorbox({
    inline: true,
    href: ".ajax",
    onCleanup: function() {
      $(".ajax").css("display", "none");
    },
  });
});

/*!
 Colorbox 1.6.4
 license: MIT
 http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox
*/
(function(t, e, i) {
  function n(i, n, o) {
    var r = e.createElement(i);
    return n && (r.id = Z + n), o && (r.style.cssText = o), t(r)
  }

  function o() {
    return i.innerHeight ? i.innerHeight : t(i).height()
  }

  function r(e, i) {
    i !== Object(i) && (i = {}), this.cache = {}, this.el = e, this.value = function(e) {
      var n;
      return void 0 === this.cache[e] && (n = t(this.el).attr("data-cbox-" + e), void 0 !== n ? this.cache[e] = n : void 0 !== i[e] ? this.cache[e] = i[e] : void 0 !== X[e] && (this.cache[e] = X[e])), this.cache[e]
    }, this.get = function(e) {
      var i = this.value(e);
      return t.isFunction(i) ? i.call(this.el, this) : i
    }
  }

  function h(t) {
    var e = W.length,
      i = (A + t) % e;
    return 0 > i ? e + i : i
  }

  function a(t, e) {
    return Math.round((/%/.test(t) ? ("x" === e ? E.width() : o()) / 100 : 1) * parseInt(t, 10))
  }

  function s(t, e) {
    return t.get("photo") || t.get("photoRegex").test(e)
  }

  function l(t, e) {
    return t.get("retinaUrl") && i.devicePixelRatio > 1 ? e.replace(t.get("photoRegex"), t.get("retinaSuffix")) : e
  }

  function d(t) {
    "contains" in x[0] && !x[0].contains(t.target) && t.target !== v[0] && (t.stopPropagation(), x.focus())
  }

  function c(t) {
    c.str !== t && (x.add(v).removeClass(c.str).addClass(t), c.str = t)
  }

  function g(e) {
    A = 0, e && e !== !1 && "nofollow" !== e ? (W = t("." + te).filter(function() {
      var i = t.data(this, Y),
        n = new r(this, i);
      return n.get("rel") === e
    }), A = W.index(_.el), -1 === A && (W = W.add(_.el), A = W.length - 1)) : W = t(_.el)
  }

  function u(i) {
    t(e).trigger(i), ae.triggerHandler(i)
  }

  function f(i) {
    var o;
    if (!G) {
      if (o = t(i).data(Y), _ = new r(i, o), g(_.get("rel")), !U) {
        U = $ = !0, c(_.get("className")), x.css({
          visibility: "hidden",
          display: "block",
          opacity: ""
        }), I = n(se, "LoadedContent", "width:0; height:0; overflow:hidden; visibility:hidden"), b.css({
          width: "",
          height: ""
        }).append(I), j = T.height() + k.height() + b.outerHeight(!0) - b.height(), D = C.width() + H.width() + b.outerWidth(!0) - b.width(), N = I.outerHeight(!0), z = I.outerWidth(!0);
        var h = a(_.get("initialWidth"), "x"),
          s = a(_.get("initialHeight"), "y"),
          l = _.get("maxWidth"),
          f = _.get("maxHeight");
        _.w = Math.max((l !== !1 ? Math.min(h, a(l, "x")) : h) - z - D, 0), _.h = Math.max((f !== !1 ? Math.min(s, a(f, "y")) : s) - N - j, 0), I.css({
          width: "",
          height: _.h
        }), J.position(), u(ee), _.get("onOpen"), O.add(F).hide(), x.focus(), _.get("trapFocus") && e.addEventListener && (e.addEventListener("focus", d, !0), ae.one(re, function() {
          e.removeEventListener("focus", d, !0)
        })), _.get("returnFocus") && ae.one(re, function() {
          t(_.el).focus()
        })
      }
      var p = parseFloat(_.get("opacity"));
      v.css({
        opacity: p === p ? p : "",
        cursor: _.get("overlayClose") ? "pointer" : "",
        visibility: "visible"
      }).show(), _.get("closeButton") ? B.html(_.get("close")).appendTo(b) : B.appendTo("<div/>"), w()
    }
  }

  function p() {
    x || (V = !1, E = t(i), x = n(se).attr({
      id: Y,
      "class": t.support.opacity === !1 ? Z + "IE" : "",
      role: "dialog",
      tabindex: "-1"
    }).hide(), v = n(se, "Overlay").hide(), L = t([n(se, "LoadingOverlay")[0], n(se, "LoadingGraphic")[0]]), y = n(se, "Wrapper"), b = n(se, "Content").append(F = n(se, "Title"), R = n(se, "Current"), P = t('<button type="button"/>').attr({
      id: Z + "Previous"
    }), K = t('<button type="button"/>').attr({
      id: Z + "Next"
    }), S = t('<button type="button"/>').attr({
      id: Z + "Slideshow"
    }), L), B = t('<button type="button"/>').attr({
      id: Z + "Close"
    }), y.append(n(se).append(n(se, "TopLeft"), T = n(se, "TopCenter"), n(se, "TopRight")), n(se, !1, "clear:left").append(C = n(se, "MiddleLeft"), b, H = n(se, "MiddleRight")), n(se, !1, "clear:left").append(n(se, "BottomLeft"), k = n(se, "BottomCenter"), n(se, "BottomRight"))).find("div div").css({
      "float": "left"
    }), M = n(se, !1, "position:absolute; width:9999px; visibility:hidden; display:none; max-width:none;"), O = K.add(P).add(R).add(S)), e.body && !x.parent().length && t(e.body).append(v, x.append(y, M))
  }

  function m() {
    function i(t) {
      t.which > 1 || t.shiftKey || t.altKey || t.metaKey || t.ctrlKey || (t.preventDefault(), f(this))
    }
    return x ? (V || (V = !0, K.click(function() {
      J.next()
    }), P.click(function() {
      J.prev()
    }), B.click(function() {
      J.close()
    }), v.click(function() {
      _.get("overlayClose") && J.close()
    }), t(e).bind("keydown." + Z, function(t) {
      var e = t.keyCode;
      U && _.get("escKey") && 27 === e && (t.preventDefault(), J.close()), U && _.get("arrowKey") && W[1] && !t.altKey && (37 === e ? (t.preventDefault(), P.click()) : 39 === e && (t.preventDefault(), K.click()))
    }), t.isFunction(t.fn.on) ? t(e).on("click." + Z, "." + te, i) : t("." + te).live("click." + Z, i)), !0) : !1
  }

  function w() {
    var e, o, r, h = J.prep,
      d = ++le;
    if ($ = !0, q = !1, u(he), u(ie), _.get("onLoad"), _.h = _.get("height") ? a(_.get("height"), "y") - N - j : _.get("innerHeight") && a(_.get("innerHeight"), "y"), _.w = _.get("width") ? a(_.get("width"), "x") - z - D : _.get("innerWidth") && a(_.get("innerWidth"), "x"), _.mw = _.w, _.mh = _.h, _.get("maxWidth") && (_.mw = a(_.get("maxWidth"), "x") - z - D, _.mw = _.w && _.w < _.mw ? _.w : _.mw), _.get("maxHeight") && (_.mh = a(_.get("maxHeight"), "y") - N - j, _.mh = _.h && _.h < _.mh ? _.h : _.mh), e = _.get("href"), Q = setTimeout(function() {
      L.show()
    }, 100), _.get("inline")) {
      var c = t(e).eq(0);
      r = t("<div>").hide().insertBefore(c), ae.one(he, function() {
        r.replaceWith(c)
      }), h(c)
    } else _.get("iframe") ? h(" ") : _.get("html") ? h(_.get("html")) : s(_, e) ? (e = l(_, e), q = _.get("createImg"), t(q).addClass(Z + "Photo").bind("error." + Z, function() {
      h(n(se, "Error").html(_.get("imgError")))
    }).one("load", function() {
      d === le && setTimeout(function() {
        var e;
        _.get("retinaImage") && i.devicePixelRatio > 1 && (q.height = q.height / i.devicePixelRatio, q.width = q.width / i.devicePixelRatio), _.get("scalePhotos") && (o = function() {
          q.height -= q.height * e, q.width -= q.width * e
        }, _.mw && q.width > _.mw && (e = (q.width - _.mw) / q.width, o()), _.mh && q.height > _.mh && (e = (q.height - _.mh) / q.height, o())), _.h && (q.style.marginTop = Math.max(_.mh - q.height, 0) / 2 + "px"), W[1] && (_.get("loop") || W[A + 1]) && (q.style.cursor = "pointer", t(q).bind("click." + Z, function() {
          J.next()
        })), q.style.width = q.width + "px", q.style.height = q.height + "px", h(q)
      }, 1)
    }), q.src = e) : e && M.load(e, _.get("data"), function(e, i) {
      d === le && h("error" === i ? n(se, "Error").html(_.get("xhrError")) : t(this).contents())
    })
  }
  var v, x, y, b, T, C, H, k, W, E, I, M, L, F, R, S, K, P, B, O, _, j, D, N, z, A, q, U, $, G, Q, J, V, X = {
      html: !1,
      photo: !1,
      iframe: !1,
      inline: !1,
      transition: "elastic",
      speed: 300,
      fadeOut: 300,
      width: !1,
      initialWidth: "600",
      innerWidth: !1,
      maxWidth: !1,
      height: !1,
      initialHeight: "450",
      innerHeight: !1,
      maxHeight: !1,
      scalePhotos: !0,
      scrolling: !0,
      opacity: .9,
      preloading: !0,
      className: !1,
      overlayClose: !0,
      escKey: !0,
      arrowKey: !0,
      top: !1,
      bottom: !1,
      left: !1,
      right: !1,
      fixed: !1,
      data: void 0,
      closeButton: !0,
      fastIframe: !0,
      open: !1,
      reposition: !0,
      loop: !0,
      slideshow: !1,
      slideshowAuto: !0,
      slideshowSpeed: 2500,
      slideshowStart: "start slideshow",
      slideshowStop: "stop slideshow",
      photoRegex: /\.(gif|png|jp(e|g|eg)|bmp|ico|webp|jxr|svg)((#|\?).*)?$/i,
      retinaImage: !1,
      retinaUrl: !1,
      retinaSuffix: "@2x.$1",
      current: "image {current} of {total}",
      previous: "previous",
      next: "next",
      close: "close",
      xhrError: "This content failed to load.",
      imgError: "This image failed to load.",
      returnFocus: !0,
      trapFocus: !0,
      onOpen: !1,
      onLoad: !1,
      onComplete: !1,
      onCleanup: !1,
      onClosed: !1,
      rel: function() {
        return this.rel
      },
      href: function() {
        return t(this).attr("href")
      },
      title: function() {
        return this.title
      },
      createImg: function() {
        var e = new Image,
          i = t(this).data("cbox-img-attrs");
        return "object" == typeof i && t.each(i, function(t, i) {
          e[t] = i
        }), e
      },
      createIframe: function() {
        var i = e.createElement("iframe"),
          n = t(this).data("cbox-iframe-attrs");
        return "object" == typeof n && t.each(n, function(t, e) {
          i[t] = e
        }), "frameBorder" in i && (i.frameBorder = 0), "allowTransparency" in i && (i.allowTransparency = "true"), i.name = (new Date).getTime(), i.allowFullscreen = !0, i
      }
    },
    Y = "colorbox",
    Z = "cbox",
    te = Z + "Element",
    ee = Z + "_open",
    ie = Z + "_load",
    ne = Z + "_complete",
    oe = Z + "_cleanup",
    re = Z + "_closed",
    he = Z + "_purge",
    ae = t("<a/>"),
    se = "div",
    le = 0,
    de = {},
    ce = function() {
      function t() {
        clearTimeout(h)
      }

      function e() {
        (_.get("loop") || W[A + 1]) && (t(), h = setTimeout(J.next, _.get("slideshowSpeed")))
      }

      function i() {
        S.html(_.get("slideshowStop")).unbind(s).one(s, n), ae.bind(ne, e).bind(ie, t), x.removeClass(a + "off").addClass(a + "on")
      }

      function n() {
        t(), ae.unbind(ne, e).unbind(ie, t), S.html(_.get("slideshowStart")).unbind(s).one(s, function() {
          J.next(), i()
        }), x.removeClass(a + "on").addClass(a + "off")
      }

      function o() {
        r = !1, S.hide(), t(), ae.unbind(ne, e).unbind(ie, t), x.removeClass(a + "off " + a + "on")
      }
      var r, h, a = Z + "Slideshow_",
        s = "click." + Z;
      return function() {
        r ? _.get("slideshow") || (ae.unbind(oe, o), o()) : _.get("slideshow") && W[1] && (r = !0, ae.one(oe, o), _.get("slideshowAuto") ? i() : n(), S.show())
      }
    }();
  t[Y] || (t(p), J = t.fn[Y] = t[Y] = function(e, i) {
    var n, o = this;
    return e = e || {}, t.isFunction(o) && (o = t("<a/>"), e.open = !0), o[0] ? (p(), m() && (i && (e.onComplete = i), o.each(function() {
      var i = t.data(this, Y) || {};
      t.data(this, Y, t.extend(i, e))
    }).addClass(te), n = new r(o[0], e), n.get("open") && f(o[0])), o) : o
  }, J.position = function(e, i) {
    function n() {
      T[0].style.width = k[0].style.width = b[0].style.width = parseInt(x[0].style.width, 10) - D + "px", b[0].style.height = C[0].style.height = H[0].style.height = parseInt(x[0].style.height, 10) - j + "px"
    }
    var r, h, s, l = 0,
      d = 0,
      c = x.offset();
    if (E.unbind("resize." + Z), x.css({
      top: -9e4,
      left: -9e4
    }), h = E.scrollTop(), s = E.scrollLeft(), _.get("fixed") ? (c.top -= h, c.left -= s, x.css({
      position: "fixed"
    })) : (l = h, d = s, x.css({
      position: "absolute"
    })), d += _.get("right") !== !1 ? Math.max(E.width() - _.w - z - D - a(_.get("right"), "x"), 0) : _.get("left") !== !1 ? a(_.get("left"), "x") : Math.round(Math.max(E.width() - _.w - z - D, 0) / 2), l += _.get("bottom") !== !1 ? Math.max(o() - _.h - N - j - a(_.get("bottom"), "y"), 0) : _.get("top") !== !1 ? a(_.get("top"), "y") : Math.round(Math.max(o() - _.h - N - j, 0) / 2), x.css({
      top: c.top,
      left: c.left,
      visibility: "visible"
    }), y[0].style.width = y[0].style.height = "9999px", r = {
      width: _.w + z + D,
      height: _.h + N + j,
      top: l,
      left: d
    }, e) {
      var g = 0;
      t.each(r, function(t) {
        return r[t] !== de[t] ? (g = e, void 0) : void 0
      }), e = g
    }
    de = r, e || x.css(r), x.dequeue().animate(r, {
      duration: e || 0,
      complete: function() {
        n(), $ = !1, y[0].style.width = _.w + z + D + "px", y[0].style.height = _.h + N + j + "px", _.get("reposition") && setTimeout(function() {
          E.bind("resize." + Z, J.position)
        }, 1), t.isFunction(i) && i()
      },
      step: n
    })
  }, J.resize = function(t) {
    var e;
    U && (t = t || {}, t.width && (_.w = a(t.width, "x") - z - D), t.innerWidth && (_.w = a(t.innerWidth, "x")), I.css({
      width: _.w
    }), t.height && (_.h = a(t.height, "y") - N - j), t.innerHeight && (_.h = a(t.innerHeight, "y")), t.innerHeight || t.height || (e = I.scrollTop(), I.css({
      height: "auto"
    }), _.h = I.height()), I.css({
      height: _.h
    }), e && I.scrollTop(e), J.position("none" === _.get("transition") ? 0 : _.get("speed")))
  }, J.prep = function(i) {
    function o() {
      return _.w = _.w || I.width(), _.w = _.mw && _.mw < _.w ? _.mw : _.w, _.w
    }

    function a() {
      return _.h = _.h || I.height(), _.h = _.mh && _.mh < _.h ? _.mh : _.h, _.h
    }
    if (U) {
      var d, g = "none" === _.get("transition") ? 0 : _.get("speed");
      I.remove(), I = n(se, "LoadedContent").append(i), I.hide().appendTo(M.show()).css({
        width: o(),
        overflow: _.get("scrolling") ? "auto" : "hidden"
      }).css({
        height: a()
      }).prependTo(b), M.hide(), t(q).css({
        "float": "none"
      }), c(_.get("className")), d = function() {
        function i() {
          t.support.opacity === !1 && x[0].style.removeAttribute("filter")
        }
        var n, o, a = W.length;
        U && (o = function() {
          clearTimeout(Q), L.hide(), u(ne), _.get("onComplete")
        }, F.html(_.get("title")).show(), I.show(), a > 1 ? ("string" == typeof _.get("current") && R.html(_.get("current").replace("{current}", A + 1).replace("{total}", a)).show(), K[_.get("loop") || a - 1 > A ? "show" : "hide"]().html(_.get("next")), P[_.get("loop") || A ? "show" : "hide"]().html(_.get("previous")), ce(), _.get("preloading") && t.each([h(-1), h(1)], function() {
          var i, n = W[this],
            o = new r(n, t.data(n, Y)),
            h = o.get("href");
          h && s(o, h) && (h = l(o, h), i = e.createElement("img"), i.src = h)
        })) : O.hide(), _.get("iframe") ? (n = _.get("createIframe"), _.get("scrolling") || (n.scrolling = "no"), t(n).attr({
          src: _.get("href"),
          "class": Z + "Iframe"
        }).one("load", o).appendTo(I), ae.one(he, function() {
          n.src = "//about:blank"
        }), _.get("fastIframe") && t(n).trigger("load")) : o(), "fade" === _.get("transition") ? x.fadeTo(g, 1, i) : i())
      }, "fade" === _.get("transition") ? x.fadeTo(g, 0, function() {
        J.position(0, d)
      }) : J.position(g, d)
    }
  }, J.next = function() {
    !$ && W[1] && (_.get("loop") || W[A + 1]) && (A = h(1), f(W[A]))
  }, J.prev = function() {
    !$ && W[1] && (_.get("loop") || A) && (A = h(-1), f(W[A]))
  }, J.close = function() {
    U && !G && (G = !0, U = !1, u(oe), _.get("onCleanup"), E.unbind("." + Z), v.fadeTo(_.get("fadeOut") || 0, 0), x.stop().fadeTo(_.get("fadeOut") || 0, 0, function() {
      x.hide(), v.hide(), u(he), I.remove(), setTimeout(function() {
        G = !1, u(re), _.get("onClosed")
      }, 1)
    }))
  }, J.remove = function() {
    x && (x.stop(), t[Y].close(), x.stop(!1, !0).remove(), v.remove(), G = !1, x = null, t("." + te).removeData(Y).removeClass(te), t(e).unbind("click." + Z).unbind("keydown." + Z))
  }, J.element = function() {
    return t(_.el)
  }, J.settings = X)
})(jQuery, document, window);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class='ajax'>Pop-up text goes here</div>
</body>
```